# Is there a good way to get the entire length of the i - argument in a data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, subset

Is there a good way to find out the length of entire data that one is working on in data.table, like with `.N` that returns the length of the group?

I give you an example:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(iris)
dt$Species[1:10] <- NA
dt[
  !is.na(Species),
  list(
    proportion = .N / 140,
    sepalwidthmean = mean(Sepal.Width)
  ),
  by = Species
]
dt[
  !is.na(Species),
  list(
    proportion = .N / sum(!is.na(dt$Species)),
    sepalwidthmean = mean(Sepal.Width)
  ),
  by = Species
]
```

As you can see, it takes quite some amount of typing to get the 140 (150-10) that is essentially redundant (already done in the I-argument of my query).

The way I did it feels a bit scary to me, because normally, data.table will look at the names of the columns instead of the names of the global scope of variables. So

```
dt$dt <- "dt"
dt[
  !is.na(Species),
  list(
    proportion = .N / sum(!is.na(dt$Species)),
    sepalwidthmean = mean(Sepal.Width),
    lalala = mean(`dt$Species`)
  ),
  by = Species
]
```

and you get `Error in dt$Species : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`. Is there an elegant way of doing it right?

It feels a bit bit like magic that normally, everything works out correctly:

```
dt$mean <- "mean"
dt[,mean(Sepal.Length)]
```

gives `5.843333` instead of an error. So maybe you can see why I want to have a better way than the one I am currently using.

Comment: I think the answer below is the most valid approach (the principal of using a second "chain"). Even if there's a hack to get the total number of rows without considering grouping, it'd be probably a bad practice. Just break your calcs into multiple steps. That's generally good idea, unless we are doing some code-golf and number bits and bites matter.

Comment: BTW, there is an open issue https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1206 about this, and it's been recently added to the Milestones, so it may get implemented after almost 10 years (who knows?).

Comment: @M-- thanks for this, which I think is a more valuable response than the workaround answer I gave. I've edited my answer to mention it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the `proportion` column in a second chained step.

```
dt[!is.na(Species), .(sepalwidthmean = mean(Sepal.Width), .N), by=Species
 ][, proportion := N/sum(N)][]

      Species sepalwidthmean     N proportion
       <fctr>          <num> <int>      <num>
1:     setosa         3.4575    40  0.2857143
2: versicolor         2.7700    50  0.3571429
3:  virginica         2.9740    50  0.3571429
```

**Edit:** On a more attentive reading, the question is really about whether, given a `data.table` query with a `by` (and potentially also an `i`) argument present, there is a neater way of getting the denominator in <group_N> / <overall_N> than re-referencing (and re-filtering) the table, in this case via e.g. `.N / sum(!is.na(dt$Species))`. This is rather cumbersome when the data are filtered in `i` and a simple `.N / nrow(dt)` won't work.

The answer above, i.e. `.N` for <group_N> then `sum(N)` for <overall_N> in a second step, is what I use for this very common pattern (and I doubt I'm alone), but doesn't really answer this point.

As @M-- points out in a comment, there is an open issue [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1206) regarding the lack of a <overall_N> equivalent of `.N` (i.e. one that ignores `by`) and a potentially breaking overhaul of the `.N`, `.I` and other symbols is a milestone for data.table 2.0.0.

In the meantime it seems that the method mentioned in the question, plus the two-step chained alternative added above, are the closest we have to a canonical way of achieving this.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. I have one small question: Can you explain why the `[]` is needed in order to print out the result? Even if I do `x <- dt[!is.na(Species), .(sepalwidthmean = mean(Sepal.Width), .N), by=Species][, proportion := N/sum(N)]`  and then execute `x` the result does not get printed (but it is there and can be shown by `print(x)` or by executing `x` a second time).

Comment: It's because `':='` and any other `set` operations in data.table are basically in-place assignments that don't return anything for evaluation and an implicit print call. `[]` basically says "do nothing" but does trigger this. My terminology is probably a bit hand-wavy here but that's the gist of it.